# How can I add quora follow button on my webpage

Tags: quora

I am trying to add quora follow button on my web page

I searched for it and got some old links that are not working now. I think quora have removed those options now. Is there some way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, the following relation, loads up Quora follow icon, needs to be included
inside head.

```
<link rel="icon" href="https://qsf.fs.quoracdn.net/-3-images.favicon.ico-26-
3f34badcb59c8f6c.ico">
```

And for button addition inside body, just create a button of a relevant size and add a hyperlink. An inspect element iterated this,

```
<g class="icon_svg-unpressed icon_svg-stroke" transform="translate(4.400000, 
4.000000)" stroke="#666" fill="none" stroke-width="1.5">
<path d="M10.5999999,12.5 C10.5999999,10.8431458 9.25685415,9.5 
7.5999999,9.5 C5.94314566,9.5 4.5999999,10.8431458 4.5999999,12.5 
M7.5999999,8.5 C8.84264059,8.5 9.8499999,7.49264069 9.8499999,6.25 
C9.8499999,5.00735931 8.84264059,4 7.5999999,4 C6.35735922,4 
5.3499999,5.00735931 5.3499999,6.25 C5.3499999,7.49264069 6.35735922,8.5 
7.5999999,8.5 Z" id="profile"></path>
<path d="M15.0999999,13 L15.0999999,18 M12.5999999,15.5 L17.5999999,15.5" 
id="plus" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
<path d="M9.0999999,15.5 L3.0999999,15.5 C1.44314566,15.5 
0.0999999046,14.1568542 0.0999999046,12.5 L0.0999999046,3.5 
C0.0999999046,1.84314575 1.44314566,0.5 3.0999999,0.5 L12.0999999,0.5 
C13.7568542,0.5 15.0999999,1.84314575 15.0999999,3.5 L15.0999999,9.5" 
id="outline" stroke-linecap="round"></path>
</g>
```