# How do I add a quora follow button on my Website?

Tags: html, css, quora

I want to add a quora follow button on my website - [Geeky Gene](https://www.geekygene.com/)

But there's no quora developer tools for that!

How can I embed a quora follow button on my side bar?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008778/how-can-i-add-quora-follow-button-on-my-webpage?

Answer (score -1):

Previously you could reach the page which would allow you to generate an embed code through https://quora.com/about/resources but this page now redirects to the parent uri, about.

Apparently Quora decided to halt the distribution of Quora Follow Button functionality through their website for some reason. So unfortunately, you can't add the said button to your website at the moment. Maybe they'll relaunch this service in the future but as of today it doesn't seem possible.

I hope this helps.